# Can javascript access DOM content on another domain?

Tags: javascript, html, web-scraping

Is there any code in javascript like `www.facebook.com.getElementById("some id").innerHTML;`?

I was thinking if there's a way I could access the tags of another website (not written by me). I want to know if I can write a script, which when run, will,for example, fill the login form of a website.

Thanks!

Comment: There's a reason CSRF is a thing we guard against.

Comment: Short answer: [No](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).

Comment: Yes and No. Yes, you can create a browser extension which will auto fill username and passwords.  No you cant create a script hosted on another website which can do this.

Comment: You would have to get your javascript to call something on your server (same origin) which could fetch and parse the HTML from another site. Perhaps using something like this on your server http://search.cpan.org/~superasn/WWW-Mechanize-Query-0.02/lib/WWW/Mechanize/Query.pm

Answer (score 1):

No there is not.

If you would request another Website you should send an AJAX request.
To prevent cross-site-scripting, most modern browsers have disabled AJAX-requests to other Domains.

There would be the possibility that you request one php file on your own domain, which would request an external site and returns the external site to you.

Then you could perform these calls.

Comment: Using this method, am I not cross-site scripting or getting involved in CSRF (as mentioned in a comment on the question)

Comment: I guess not since you are just calling your domain